Android Question : Zygote : Process 1882 exited cleanly (255), can anyone explain this?
my running service was killed because of this, but i cannot figure out, help!
my service runned on TV, I found this message during looking throught the log.
please help me find out waht does "Zygote  : Process 1882 exited cleanly (255)" mean! I really need help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
